# Polarizing beam splitter for diagonal polarization of photons?

Tags: optics, atomic-physics, quantum-optics

If 4-fold photons which are bunched from an attenuated classical source are polarized at 45 degree (diagonally polarized) and put into polarizing beam splitter, two of them are reflected and the other two are transmitted? Is there a case where one is reflected and three are transmitted?

[image]

Comment: Draw a sketch to explain what you mean. And by folded do you mean entangled?

Comment: Added figure. It means bunched photon belonging to classical light. But it doesn't matter if they're entangled because I don't see any difference.

Answer (score 1):

If the beam splitter is a non-polarising device and the setup is ideal, then statistically 50% of the photons go in one direction and 50% in the other.

But this does not mean that at any point in time the ratio is 2:2. All other scenarios - with lower probability - are possible: 4:0, 3:1, 1:3 and 0:4.

Comment: Thank you for your interest in my question. It is useful.